# accessing HttpServletRequest object in Spring WebFlow

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I am using WebFlow and would like to add the current Locale into the flow. 
I already have a resolveLocale method that does this with this signature:

```
public Locale resolveLocale (HttpServletRequest request);
```

I would like to add something like this in my WebFlow XML:

```
<on-start>
<evaluate expression="localeService.resolveLocale(???)" result="flowScope.locale"/>
</on-start>
```

Now, I don't know what to put in the ??? parameter part. 
Any ideas? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used Web Flow, but presuming it's similar to the rest of Spring, you can use the RequestContextHolder for this. A quick Google search suggests that Web Flow even gives you a [web flow specific RequestContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContextHolder.html) - even better

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to access the locale is spring's LocaleContextHolder

Just call: LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html

Answer (score 2):

you can get HttpServletRequest in this style

```
(HttpServletRequest)RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getExternalContext().getNativeRequest()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your hints. I'm using the following line in my service (my SWF-config uses the SessionLocaleResolver):

```
Locale locale = (Locale) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().getAttribute(SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
```